# UITableView in a View controller by a UIViewController and not a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, datasource

I have a View with lots of things inside it including buttons, a scroll view and a tableView (ipad app). I am controller this view with a viewController subclass but I don't know how to manage my tableView. I don't know where put the methods :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

should I add them to my ViewController or should I create a new subclass of UITableViewController (and get them "for free") and set the dataSource and delegate of my tableView to that class when I create it programmatically?

I am storing the data I want to show in my appDelegate

.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the UIViewController as the delegate and dataSource of your UITableView. That's it. You don't need to create a own subclass of UITableViewController for managing that tableView. So you can put all the subviews in the viewController's view.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much, I got it. I was trying to create a tableView and then set it's datasource. In fact the easier way is to create a tableViewController and use it's .view property that is already linked to it and use the addSubview method to put it in the main viewController's view.

Cheers

Comment: 5 years later and you helped me solve an issue I was having with dynamic cell height. For some reason, if you add a tableView in a view controller in storyboard the cells don't grow dynamically, but when you add a tableViewController's `view` to your view controller's `view`, it works. Thanks for posting.